# некоторые цвета фона в tailwind не работают

Tags: css, laravel, tailwindcss

я эксперементирую с пакетом laravel jetstream livewire.
установил все по инструкции и прохожу туториал в Youtube.

некоторые классы цвета фона например `.bg-green-600` не работают. их просто нет в файле public\css\app.css

на родной странице tailwind не нашел информации, где что искать и как чинить - только как использовать.

я пытался скомпилировать исходники:. `npm run dev` но это не помогло.

laravel `v9.13.0` tailwind `v3.0.24`

помогите понять куда делись цвета фона и как их вернуть? как вообще решать такие проблемы? где искать информацию?

Answer (score 0):

нашел не универсально, но приемлемое решение:
причина не совсем ясна - не все цвета автоматически импортируются и что бы при компиляции иметь доступ к цветам, надо в файле
`tailwind.config.js` импортировать цвета

```
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')
```

тогда при компиляции

```
npm run dev
```

цвета, которые есть в коде будут скомпилированы в `public\css\app.css`